# Installing php_apc.dll on wampserver

Tags: installation, php, web-development, php-apc

I need your help. I'm trying to install php_apc.dll into my 
php directory.

So far this is what i've done:

I copied php_apc.dll to c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\ext. I've also restarted the server several times.

But when i checked

```
 http://localhost/?phpinfo=1
```

There wasnt any evidence of APC Extension Installation.

Please what i'm i doing wrong?
I'll be most delighted with your answers, comments and suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must add the following line in your php.ini under apache \bin

```
[APC]
apc.enabled = 1
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 64M
apc.max_file_size = 10M
apc.stat = 1
```

Also, please make sure that the php_apc is checked in your wamp server panel.

This question is related to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9916701/1160296